# Grails different versions in ubuntu

Tags: bashrc

I am using **`grails 2.4.0`** for my recent grails application. Now I have cloned a grails-app which is developed in **`grails 2.0.4`**. My **`grails path is pointing to 2.4.0`**, so that I just upgraded the 2.0.4 application into 2.4.0.

Now some methods and classes are found deprecated, and some codes are found damaged. After that I have cloned the previous 2.0.4 and start running with 2.0.4 by editing the bashrc into 2.0.4.

But I need to edit both the applications simultaneously.

Is there any way to switch between 2.0.4 and 2.4.0 with out editing bashrc every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gvm can install, upgrade, and switch versions of common Groovy tools, including Grails, so you don't need to edit your environment by hand. 
http://gvmtool.net/

Comment: thanqq....forknowledge sharing...
good solution.